# Data replication between SQL server 2008 R2 and other NOSQL DB (ML, MongoDB)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, nosql

I'm a newbie in RDBMs and I have the question regarding replication between SQL Server (Oracle in future) and NOSQL MarkLogic server (ML).

There are two servers:

1. Machine with SQL server 2008 R2 (Standard edition)
2. Machine with MarkLogic server.

SQL server has a lot of tables (data1, data2, ....., data200) with rows that can be changed, removed or added.

My goal is to provide replication between servers.

I need to retrieve data from SQL server and save it to ML. There is no problem with it. I can execute SQL query from ML server.
But, the most important thing is tracking changes in those tables. Of course, I could retrieve all data from all tables and compare it with existing data in ML, but it is very expensive.

So, I see few ways to resolve my problem:

1. As far as I know I can to get last modify data of each table.

SELECT modify_date FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'data1';

ML server could to check SQL's tables every 1 or 2 minutes and retrieve data from modified tables.

1. Create procedure that would send http-post when the data changed. I've heard that isn't good idea.
2. Use capture data, but it isn't my way, because CD is supported by SQL server enterprise.
3. ML server has own ODBC driver, Maybe can somehow to use it?

Are there any more ways or good practice to replicate data between SQL server 2008 R2 and other NOSQL DB (ML, MongoDB and other.)?

Thanks.

Comment: Replication from SQL Server to NOSQL databases is **not** supported. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151864(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Yes, but I want a kind of "replication" by hands. Are there good practice?

Comment: I am trying to do something similar. Would appreciate it if you could share your learnings @AndrewOrlov

Comment: @smartnut007, actually I haven't found any adequate solution.Back then, I wrote an some kind of adapter on C# that was fetching a data from SQL Server and pushing it to ML. It's long since I was trying to managed with that problem, so maybe for now there is a possibility to get this done using native MarkLogic or MongoDb solution.